# Prevent form redirection if validation fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am making a function in JS that prevents you from submitting if there is something wrong.

When I click the submit button it does not check if the code is valid, which really bugs me. My expected outcome is to redirect to another page if it is valid, which doesn't happen! Please help!

```js
const formm = document.querySelector('#CreateAccount')
const school = document.querySelector('#skool');
const username = document.querySelector('#username');
const email = document.querySelector('#email');
const pwd = document.querySelector('#password');
const conf = document.querySelector('#confpassword');

formm.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
  if (isFormValid() == true) {
    window.location.assign("start.html");
    console.log(2);
  } else {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(30);
  }
  validateForm();
  console.log(30);
});


function isFormValid() {
  const inputscontainers = document.querySelectorAll('.inputs')
  let result = true;
  inputscontainers.forEach((container) => {
    if (container.classList.contains("error")) {
      return false;
    }
  })
}

function validateForm() {
  if (username.value.trim() == '') {
    setError(username, 'Name cannot be empty');
  } else if (username.value.trim() < 5) {
    setError(username, 'Idrc');
    console.log(3);
  } else {
    setSuccess(username);
  }
  if (email.value.trim() == '') {
    setError(email, 'You forgot to fill in your email.');
  } else if (isEmailValid(email.value)) {
    setSuccess(email);
  } else {
    setError(email, "Provide a valid email");
  }
  if (pwd.value.trim() == '') {
    setError(pwd, "Password can't be empty");
  } else if (pwd.value.trim().length < 6 || pwd.value.trim().length > 20) {
    setError(pwd, 'Length must be minimum 6 characters and max 20.');
  } else {
    setSuccess(pwd);
  }
  if (conf.value.trim() == '') {
    setError(conf, 'This is an empty password');
  } else if (conf.value !== pwd.value) {
    setError(conf, 'Passwords dont match');
  } else {
    setSuccess(conf);
  }



}

function setError(elementr, errorMessage) {
  const parents = elementr.parentElement;
  parents.classList.add("error");
  parents.classList.remove("success");
  const paragraph = parents.querySelector('p').textContent = errorMessage;
}

function setSuccess(elementr) {
  const parents = elementr.parentElement;
  parents.classList.add("success");
  parents.classList.remove("error");
}

function isEmailValid(email) {
  const reg = /^(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i;
  return reg.test(email);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="CreateAccount" action="start.html" method="GET">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="Title">
      <h1>Enter your details.</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="inputs">
      <label for="skool">SchoolName:</label>
      <input type="text" id="skool" placeholder="Put the school name" name="skool"></input>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-xmark"></i>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check"></i>
      <p>Error Message</p>
    </div>
    <div class="inputs">
      <label for="username">Username:</label>
      <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Username" name="username">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-xmark"></i>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check"></i>
      <p id="p">Error Message</p>
    </div>
    <div class="inputs">
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="    Password" name="password"></input>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-xmark"></i>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check"></i>
      <p id="p">Error Message</p>
    </div>
    <div class="inputs">
      <label for="confpassword">Confirm Password</label>
      <input type="password" id="confpassword" placeholder="    Confirm Password" name="confpassword"></input>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-xmark"></i>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check"></i>
      <p>Error Message</p>
    </div>
    <div class="inputs">
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email"></input>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-xmark"></i>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check"></i>
      <p>Error Message</p>
    </div>
    <button class="submitbtn" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You are running `validateForm();` AFTER `if(isFormValid() == true)`, you need to validate first, then check if the form is valid

Comment: @savageGoat i tried that but nothing!

Comment: What's the console output after that change?

Answer (score 0):

Other than the inversion on `validation` / `isValidForm`, your `isValidForm` function doesn't return a result, so it can't be compared on a if statement
Here's how to fix it

```
    formm.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
        validateForm();
        if (isFormValid() == true) {
            window.location.assign("start.html");
        } else {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });


    function isFormValid() {
        const inputscontainers = document.querySelectorAll('.inputs')
        let result = true;
        inputscontainers.forEach((container) => {
            if (container.classList.contains("error")) {
                return false;
            }
        })
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: the only change is the last lin right?

Comment: And validation before the check. The validation `validateForm` sets the `.error` or `.success` class, then `isFormValid` checks if the classes set by `validateForm` are in the parent